Modulenotfounderror in output of vscode
Like I'm creating a website where the python is the backend of the website which runs ML code but the problem is the output of my python shows that the flask module is not found but in the terminal section it shows no error and my python code starts to run on localhost 5000. Is it a problem that the terminal section found no error and runs smoothly but the output shows an error for flask not found???
If anyone faced this problem please respond and I'm not a coder. I'm just using ai chatgpt to create the website

To get better answers on this you should add the error output. However you will probably need to do some coding to fix the problem
